# Elasticsearch for mysql view rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

How to create an elasticsearch index for a view in MYSQL  ?

I tried making a model for a migration of a mysql view and in the model put

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

and put in `elasticsearch.rb`

```
unless client.indices.exists? index: 'history_views'
HistoryView.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
end

HistoryView.import
```

but it seems that the line `HistoryView.import`
gives an error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'history_views.' in 'order clause': SELECT history_views.* FROM history_views ORDER BY history_views. ASC LIMIT 1000

I think the gem needs a primary key to order by it and that is not present in the view .

How can I solve this ? 
Do I have to override some function in the gem ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is the issue :

**A primary key is needed which is not present in the MYSQL view**

So added the line in the model.rb

```
  self.primary_key = 'id'
```

to create the primary key.

Note : id is in the select query for the view.